# Responsiveness working after a page-refresh? (HTML rendering delayed)

Tags: javascript, css, templates, prestashop, responsiveness

When I change the screensize to a phone or something smaller than 768px, the search bar is displayed at the top and moved
to its right position first after a refresh of the page. Yet it should be right in place from start on. And when I resize the screen back to full width, it is missing until the page is refreshed.
You can check the behavior [link deleted]and just switch to some phone screen in browser console.

The js for this behavior is

```
    function searchwidget(){

if ($(document).width() <= 767)
{
    $('#search_widget').appendTo('.hidden-md-up.text-xs-center.mobile');
}
else if($(document).width() >= 768)
{
    $('.header-top #search_widget').prependTo('.right-nav');
}
```

This is the template code

```
{block name='header_nav'}
   <nav class="header-nav">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hidden-sm-down">
       <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm-down" id="_desktop_logo">
            <a href="{$urls.base_url}" class="header-logo">
              <img class="logo img-responsive" src="{$shop.logo}" alt="{$shop.name}">
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 left-nav">
          {hook h='displayNav1'}
        </div>
      
        <div class="col-md-3 right-nav">
            {hook h='displayNav2'}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-md-up text-xs-center mobile">
       
        <div class="pull-xs-right" id="_mobile_user_info"></div>
        <div class="pull-xs-right" id="_mobile_cart"></div>
        <div class="pull-xs-left" id="menu-icon">
          <i class="material-icons d-inline">&#xE5D2;</i>
        </div>
        <div class="top-logo" id="_mobile_logo"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

{/block}

How to fix this?

Comment: I am guessing your `searchwidget` function that explicitly places the element in one of two positions in the DOM, only gets called once - but it would have to get called after the viewport has been resized as well.

Comment: Yes, maybe. Do you know a solution?

Comment: Well call it again, using a resize handler?

Comment: If that was only so easy :) This is custom theme, for prestashop and I'm struggling all the time to find the stuff I'm looking for. I'm not a good web-developer. I don't know where to look for the resize handler. Would be nice if you could at least tell me that?

Comment: _"I don't know where to look for the resize handler."_ - there isn't necessarily one already, so add your own.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work. Okay, I'm gonna look up resize handler. Thanks so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252872/discussion-between-utility-monster-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CBroe
part of the solution is

```
function searchwidget(){
    
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
if ($(document).width() <= 767)
{
        $('#search_widget').appendTo('.hidden-md-up.text-xs-center.mobile');
    }
    else if($(document).width() >= 768)
    {
        $('.header-top #search_widget').prependTo('.right-nav');
    }
}, true);
}
```